# Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "App\Twig\AppExtension"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I am new to learning symfony4. I have a problem to use the doctrine in the twig extension. How to use the doctrine query in twig extension.

please help me how to configure the service for this code

```
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
     public function getFilters(): array
    {
        return [
            // If your filter generates SAFE HTML, you should add a third
            // parameter: ['is_safe' => ['html']]
            // Reference: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#automatic-escaping
            new TwigFilter('filter_name', [$this, 'doSomething']),
        ];
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('followed', [$this, 'doSomething']),
        ];
    }

    public function doSomething($id, $admin)
    {
        // ...
        $follower = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Follower::class)->findAll();
        foreach( $follower as $value ){
            if($value['user']==$admin && $value['followed_user']==$id) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my twig function code

`{% if followed(users.id, app.user.id) %}`

The error occurs when I run the page
***Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class "App\Twig\AppExtension".***

Please help me to provide the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this and now the problem solved

```
    use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

    public function doSomething($id, $admin)
    {
        // ...
        $follower = $this->em->getRepository(Follower::class)->findBy([
            'followed_user' => $id,
            'user' => $admin
        ]);

        if(sizeof($follower)>0) return false;
        else return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`getDoctine` is a function defined in `AbstractController` (or `ControllerTrait` to be precise) and is not available on Twig extensions. You need to inject the `doctrine` service into your class. Most of your code omitted for brevity:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        $this->em = $registry;
    }

    public function doSomething($id, $admin)
    {
        $follower = $this->em->getRepository(Follower::class)->findAll();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the error occurs is  **An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Class App\Twig\Follower does not exist")**

Comment: I have the namespace for the follower is **App\Entity\Follower**

Comment: The `use` directive for the class is missing, but you could also pass it as a string and not include it `getRepository('App\Entity\Follower')` (although I wouldn't recommend it, the refactor tools in your IDE won't work).

Comment: Once again error message occurs is **Cannot use object of type App\Entity\Follower as array**

Comment: @babloo This has nothing to do with doctrine. `$value` is an object, you are using array access to get properties `$value['user']`. Use `$value->getUser().

Comment: please help me again to solve my problem, now error **An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Object of class App\Entity\User could not be converted to int").**